InDesign+GREP: How change currency to specific table cells that have a specific Paragraph style assigned to them?
I have a table that has two columns of currency values with a paragraph style that adds a "$" as a bullet. When I copy my values into the columns, they format just fine but are missing the ".00" decimal at the end of each one. It currently looks like "$2347," and I would like to change it to "$2,347.00" I just can't figure out how to make that happen with GREP. Any help is appreciated.
~Erick
Tried to find any number \b[/d+]\b that contains a specific paragraph style and then add ".00" but can't seem to figure out those commands. Not sure if it's even possible. Super wet behind the ears when it comes to GREP, so apologies if I'm way off. Thanks.

See https://regex101.com/r/nVyo1I/1
